# Is there any way to search from list of instances and display a specific one with user input

Tags: c#, class, object, instance

I have created a class (C#) "class Car" and created 3 instances of that class.
Car mycar,Car my2car,Car my3car.I have also given them the properties.Make,model,Year and Color.

Like this (it is one of the instance of Car class):

```
static void Main()
{
    Car mycar = new Car();
    mycar.Make = "tata";
    mycar.Model = "harrier";
    mycar.Year = "2019";
    mycar.Color = "yellow";
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way that when user input any property of a specific instance,it should display all the information of that instance

Like if I ask user to input the Model name only,console can search from all instances and display rest of the details of the related instance only.
so if I ask user... "enter the Model name" and he enters "harrier".
Then the console can display Tata,harrier,2019,yellow.

Sorry for my English, it is not my primary language and also I have just started with Programming.
Thank you.

Comment: yes there is way, but we want you to try first. If you tried already then show us your attempt

Comment: Once you have a list of objects - in your case `List<Car>` - search the web for _LINQ_ and _Where_. That should give you a good starting point.